# Gmail email composer: How to turn off the autocorrection feature?

Tags: gmail

I do not want gmail typing my emails.

I find it really annoying that as I type, the gmail editor auto corrects / automatically types for me.

How do I turn that automatic stuff off?  (The recent in line autocorrection feature, and suggestions, and everything that is not my manual input.)

Answer (score 2):

You know, I searched the net for answer, found none.

But looking in Settings, there it is...

[image]